# Cannot run my selenium tests on the edge webDriver

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm using a macOS, I installed the Edge webdriver on it, configured its path on my selenium framework

But I got this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Microsoft Edge binary
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'MacBook-Pro-de-Sabrine-2.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4c2:e6bc:d2ff:348c%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
```

Comment: Please share your code and path of the Microsoft Edge binary.

Comment: Can you please try to post your sample code and steps you had taken for set up the framework and driver? We will try to check it and try to provide suggestions for it if there is anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using MAC. The problem is that the browser needs to be installed on your system in order to run it. 
So if somehow you have installed it use the below code:

**Code:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","/YOUR_PATH");
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

OR

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","YOUR_PATH");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions  = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("/YOUR_PATH");
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions().merge(chromeOptions);
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```